# Xamarin HttpClient method GetAsync timeout error

Tags: c#, api, xamarin

I have created an api to get data but it is showing timeout error. I am calling the function inside main function of Xamarin that is called when app is run.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.BindingContext = new PatientViewModel();
        Task<PatientModel> abc = GetPatientData();
    }
```

my function for api GetAsync call:

```
public async Task<PatientModel> GetPatientData()
    {
        PatientModel patient = null;
        try
        {
            Uri weburl = new Uri("myuri");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("a");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(weburl);
            Console.WriteLine("b");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("in");
                patient = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<PatientModel>();
                Console.WriteLine("in funciton");
                return patient;
            }
            return patient;
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return patient;
        }
    }
}
```

Code is not showing any error. When execution went to GetAsync statement it waits for a while and exception occurs.

```
System.Net.WebException: The request timed out. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Exception of type 'Foundation.NSErrorException' was thrown.
```

Comment: have you checked whether or not the server is reachable and responding within the timeout window?

Comment: you mean the api url? api url is working perfectly. I have tested it in postman where I get prefect result.

Comment: What are you doing with `Task<PatientModel> abc` after the constructor?

Comment: Are you sure it's a `GET` not a `POST` ?

Comment: is it reachable from the device or emulator?

Comment: @JSteward I will render the data after fetching data. At the moment I just want to fetch the data.

Comment: @Neil Yes its Get, I am have POST as well which is working fine.

Comment: @Jason I have tested it with postman in my pc. I have done post api call in same url which is working fine from my device.

Comment: @LamaMadan it is an NSErrorException, which means it is backed by an native NSError, what is that error and stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using an async event handler along with a static `HttpClient`

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public MainPage() {
    InitializeComponent();
    loadingData += onLoadingData;        
}

protected override void OnAppearing() {
    //loadingData -= onLoadingData; //(optional)
    loadingData(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    base.OnAppearing();
}

private event EventHandler loadingData = delegate { };

private async void onLoadingData(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    var model = await GetPatientData();
    this.BindingContext = new PatientViewModel(model);
}

public async Task<PatientModel> GetPatientData() {
    PatientModel patient = null;
    try {
        Uri weburl = new Uri("myuri");
        Console.WriteLine("a");
        var response = await client.GetAsync(weburl);
        Console.WriteLine("b");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            Console.WriteLine("in");
            patient = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<PatientModel>();
            Console.WriteLine("in funciton");
        }           
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    return patient;
}
```

Using this pattern can help avoid blocking calls and socket exhaustion that can at times lead to deadlocks that could cause the timeouts experienced.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Reference [You're using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public PatientModel abc { get; set; }

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Bridge();

    // Using abc
}

public async void Bridge()
{
    abc = new PatientModel();
    abc = await GetPatientData();
}

public async Task<PatientModel> GetPatientData()
{
    PatientModel patient = null;
    try
    {
        Uri weburl = new Uri("myuri");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("a");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(weburl);
        Console.WriteLine("b");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("in");
            patient = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<PatientModel>();
            Console.WriteLine("in funciton");
            return patient;
        }
        return patient;
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        return patient;
    }
}
```